# Сериализация из List<T> в JSON. Unity, JSONUtility

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

Проблема - не сериализуется `List<ObjectData>`. При попытке выходная строка = `{}`. Объекты присутствуют. При попытке вместо List сериализовать только объект ObjectData, всё получилось.

Все классы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneSave : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] SavedObject[] _objects;
    private const string _fileName = "_data.json";
    private void Start() =>
        LoadData(); 

    public void SaveData()
    {
        var datas = new List<ObjectData>();
        foreach (var obj in _objects)
            datas.Add(obj.GetData());

        using StreamWriter writer = new(Application.persistentDataPath + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name + _fileName);
        var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(datas);
        writer.Write(json);
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            using StreamReader reader = new(Application.persistentDataPath + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name + _fileName);
            var data = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<ObjectData>>(reader.ReadToEnd());

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
                _objects[i].LoadData(data[i]);
        }
        catch { Debug.Log("File can`t found"); }
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SavedObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ObjectData GetData() =>
        new()
        {
            Position = transform.position,
            Rotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles,
            Scale = transform.localScale,
            IsActive = gameObject.activeSelf
        };

    public void LoadData(ObjectData data)
    {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " | " + data.IsActive);

        transform.SetPositionAndRotation(data.Position, Quaternion.Euler(data.Rotation));
        transform.localScale = data.Scale;
        gameObject.SetActive(data.IsActive);
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectData
{
    public Vector3 Position; 
    public Vector3 Rotation; 
    public Vector3 Scale; 
    public bool IsActive; 
}
```

Comment: [Unity C# JsonUtility is not serializing a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41787091/312041)

Comment: vector3 и quaternion не сериализуются вроде бы.

Comment: Ещё поизучайте ScriptableObject, и для чего он нужен.

Answer (score 0):

В твоем случаи, тебе вообще не нужно хранить такое в JSON. Его как минимум не для этого придумали. Тебе бы это все дело в бинарном формате хранить и желательно использовать побитовые алгоритмы. Для скорости.

Answer (score -1):

В моём случае я не поставил `[Serializable]` к сериализуемым классам